# Working Capistrano recipe for uploading precompiled Rails 3.1 assets to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline

We have a Rails 3.1 app that allows users to upload photos to Amazon S3. Since we're using S3 in production I'd like to automatically (on `cap deploy`) also upload the precompiled assets (application.js & application.css & images) to our S3 bucket where they'll be served. Simple enough.

Beyond setting `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"`

In short, **I'm looking for some examples of a working "recipe" for Capistrano to do so** but can't seem to find any modern (3.1 asset pipeline compatible) ones. We are successfully precompiling the assets but how to move them to S3? *And, ideally, only the ones that have changed?*

"Meat" of current "recipe":

```
...

after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:pipeline_precompile"
before "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:copy_database_config"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  # copy database.yml into project
  task :copy_database_config do
    production_db_config = "/path_to_config/#{application}.yml"
    run "cp #{production_db_config} #{current_release}/config/database.yml"
    `puts "replaced database.yml with live copy"`
  end
  task :pipeline_precompile do
    run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While this doesn't directly answer the question of uploading your assets to S3 on deploy, I think the following approach may address your goals and be a little simpler to implement.

The primary benefits of hosting assets on S3 and using the `config.action_controller.asset_host` directive include (among others):

- allowing additional simultaneous downloads of assets
- serving assets from a cookie-free domain

Rather than using s3, you can use the [CloudFront CDN](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to achieve the same benefits. The new rails asset pipeline plays very nicely with CloudFront. Here are the steps I am currently using in production:

**Create a new CloudFront distribution**

1. Delivery Method should be *Download*
2. Choose *Custom Origin* and point it to your web server
3. For *Distribution Details* you can add addition CNAME records such as `cdn01.mydomain.com` etc.
4. *Default Root Object* can be left empty

If your site is served over SSL, you will need to use the `x12whx1751nfir.cloudfront.net` style hostname as custom certificates are not available yet as they are with ELB and your users will see certificate hostname mismatch errors. If you don't use SSL, you can use the either the default hostname or any CNAMEs prodvided.

Once this is setup, the initial object requests will be fetched from your server and placed within CloudFront. The digest fingerprints generated by the asset pipeline will handle your requirement for only sending assets which have changed.

Comment: +1 great answer. can you also elaborate little more or point to any links on "If your site is served over SSL, you will need to use the x12whx1751nfir.cloudfront.net" please? Thanks!

Comment: When you setup a CloudFront distribution, a random hostname such as `x12whx1751nfir.cloudfront.net` will be created. You can optionally attach custom CNAME dns records such as `cdn.mydomain.com`.

If you use SSL on your website, all assets must be served over SSL or users will receive a mixed content warning. CloudFront does not support custom SSL certificates, so you much use the `x12whx1751nfir.cloudfront.net` hostname which support both HTTP and HTTPS.

If you don't use SSL, you can use the custom CNAME records such as `cdn.mydomain.com`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: so basically you are saying that for my ssl content i should refer them "ht tps://x12whx1751nfir.cloudfront.net/assets/whatever.jpg" ?

Comment: When you setup CloudFront as your asset host, you will need to configure the `config.action_controller.asset_host` directive in your `config/environments/production.rb` file. If you use SSL in production, it should look like: `config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://x12whx1751nfir.cloudfront.net"`. If you don't use SSL, you can use the same hostname, or you could use your custom CNAMEs such as: `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn.mydomain.com"` or even `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://cdn%d.mydomain.com"` if you have multiple CNAME records.

Comment: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-controller or http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets for more information.

Comment: I am gonna need this soon. Thanks a lot for explaining and helping!

Answer (score 9):

Update capistrano and include the following in your deploy file

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Comment: It is my understanding that this just handles the **precompile** - making `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` in my example above, redundant. Perhaps I'm wrong? If so, I'd love to know how that little line automatically authenticate and upload assets to an S3 bucket?!?

Comment: oh snap, this is a case of not reading the question fully. Can you not use cloud front to auto mirror assets on the domain?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem if you want to use S3. I am trying to get mine to work with [Rackspace Cloud Files](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/), but having a few problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jammit-s3](https://github.com/railsjedi/jammit-s3) gem. I configured and using it. It's perfect and has very simple configuration.